# Compiler output within new vim window

Tags: vim

Is anyone aware of any plugins or capabilities that would allow me to run bjam from with vim and then write the result to a separate window? I've been looking at the SimpleCompile plugin (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) but can't see who to adapt it.

Comment: This kind of thing barely even warrants a mapping. :new|r!echo #:p:h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A general solution** (i.e. not bjam-specific): First, configure Vim to run `bjam` for the `:make` command:

```
:set makeprg=bjam
```

Then, simply run make and show the output in a [quickfix window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix-window):

```
:make | copen
```

Alternatively, you can also simply read the output of an external command into the current buffer:

```
:r !bjam
```

Combine this with creating a new window via `:new` and you can easily read the output of an external command into a new window:

```
:new | r !bjam
```